Definition of continuity rephrased epsilon delta (need help checking my intuition)
I am trying to rephrase the definition of continuity to see if I have the right intuition. Please comment on how I might be wrong or misunderstanding something:
A function f is continuous at a point $x=a$ if when you fix $x=a$ and fix $\epsilon$ there is a delta neighborhood around $x=a$ which will ensure that any $x$ in that neighborhood $\neq$ a will ensure an $f(x)$ that is in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(a)$. But if you keep the same $\epsilon$ and fix another $x=b$, the delta neighborhood you need around that new $x=b$ may not be the same as the first one to ensure that all the members of the neighborhood ensure an $f(x)$ in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(b)$

This is not a question... The definition defines continuity at x=a, not continuity at x=b

What is the question ?

If for any $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ and that $\delta$ works for all $x$, then this property is called "uniform continuity", and such a function is called "uniformly continuous"

@Euclid thank you; It seems like you are saying my definition is for uniform continuity;  I am not sure how to modify my rephrased definition to have it define continuity instead of uniform continuity

@SimonPitte my bad; I have edited the prompt. I am basically rephrasing the definition to see if I have the right intuition of how it works, and of course inviting feed back on how it might be wrong

@WyattKuehster I have edited the prompt. I am basically rephrasing the definition to see if I have the right intuition of how it works, and of course inviting feed back on how it might be wrong

Your definition of continuity is correct, i e., the part until the word "But". What comes after it is true as well, as you say "may not be". What I wrote about uniform continuity is additional just FYI.

@Euclid thank you; in your definition of uniform continuity when you say "that delta works for all x" you mean irrespective of where you fix x, given the same epsilon you will not need to adjust delta right?

Yes. See my answer.

Please check my edits for formatting

Your definition of continuity is correct, i.e. (slightly modified for better wording),

A function $f$ is continuous at a point $x=a$ if when you fix $a$ and fix any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ neighborhood around $a$ which will ensure that any $x$ in that neighborhood ensures an $f(x)$ that is in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(a)$.

In mathematical terms (assuming $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ for simplicity), $$\forall a \quad \forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \ni \quad |x-a|<\delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
What you wrote after this definition is correct too. In general, we have the following (again slightly modified),

If you keep the same $\epsilon$ and fix another $b$, the $\delta$ neighborhood you need around that new $b$ may not be the same as the first one to ensure that all $x$ in the $\delta$ neighborhood of $b$ ensure an $f(x)$ in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $f(b)$.

As an additional information, when for any $\epsilon$ the same $\delta$ ensures it for any other $b$, the function $f$ is said to be uniformly continuous. In mathematical terms, uniform continuity is $$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \ni \quad \forall a \ , \ |x-a|<\delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
